# How to fill a region within a 2d array?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of zero number with a region in it defined by outline of number 1.

like this image:

[image: like this image]

Now I want to find all the items in that region, consisting of an outline and number zero inside it. how to I do that?

I tried use scanline method, but it didn't work because of concave region.

the sample array:

```
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 
 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 
 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 
 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 
 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

sample output: array coordinate of items within region:
[(1,4), (1,5), (1,6), (1,7), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (2,6), (2,7), ....etc]

Comment: Check every zero and its 4 directions. Up, down, left and right. Check until you find a 1. If all 4 are true, that zero is in a region. Could you provide the example array as code?

Comment: Search for fill algorithms in computer graphics.

Comment: You can use a *"flood-fill"*. Starting at top-left zero, change every zero that touches it into 255. Your answer at the end is every element that is not 255. All image processing packages can do this https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0

Comment: fill algorithms like flood fill doesn't work because it just fill items that have the same value, in my case, I need to fill items have different value- 0 and 1

Comment: I was suggesting filling the zeroes **outside** your area and taking the complement of the result.

Comment: @MarkSetchell how to find the top-left outside item with data like this?: https://gist.github.com/hoainam1593/7707757886fb6b6d40e62ce75c9fe3af

Comment: What is the format of the output you expect? Can you provide it in your question for the example you have given? What should happen when "inside" such area there are several scattered "1" cells, or even dividing the region into partitions, or with areas-within-areas, ...etc.

Comment: The normal process, if it is possible that your objects are touching the edge, is to pad your array all the way around the edges with a one-element wide/tall set of zeroes, then the flood-filling can *"flow"* all around the edges.

Comment: What should happen when "inside" such area there are several scattered "1" cells, or even dividing the region into partitions, or with areas-within-areas, ...etc.

Comment: OpenCV has function `findContours`. I don't know about its alogorithm, but I know OpenCV's manual indicates the paper name : `Satoshi Suzuki and others. Topological structural analysis of digitized binary images by border following. Computer Vision, Graphics, and Image Processing, 30(1):32–46, 1985.`. I guess check this paper can be one way. (PDF can be found from Google Scholar)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient algorithm, but you could do it like this:

```js
const arrayData = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

let enclosedCoordinates = [];

arrayData.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
  // Skip first and last row
  if (!rowIndex || rowIndex === arrayData.length - 1) {
    return;
  }
  row.forEach((cell, cellIndex) => {
    // Skip first and last cell or cells that contain 1
    if (!cellIndex || cellIndex === arrayData.length - 1 || cell > 0) {
      return;
    }

    let searchIndex = cellIndex;

    let leftEnclosed = false;
    let rightEnclosed = false;
    let upEnclosed = false;
    let downEnclosed = false;

    // Check left
    while (searchIndex > 0 && !leftEnclosed) {
      if (arrayData[rowIndex][searchIndex] === 1) {
        leftEnclosed = true;
      }
      searchIndex--;
    }

    // Reset searchIndex
    searchIndex = cellIndex;

    // Check right
    while (searchIndex < row.length - 1 && !rightEnclosed) {
      if (arrayData[rowIndex][searchIndex] === 1) {
        rightEnclosed = true;
      }
      searchIndex++;
    }

    // Reset searchIndex
    searchIndex = rowIndex;

    // Check up
    while (searchIndex > 0 && !upEnclosed) {
      if (arrayData[searchIndex][cellIndex] === 1) {
        upEnclosed = true;
      }
      searchIndex--;
    }
    
    // Reset searchIndex
    searchIndex = rowIndex;

    // Check down
    while (searchIndex < arrayData.length - 1 && !downEnclosed) {
      if (arrayData[searchIndex][cellIndex] === 1) {
        downEnclosed = true;
      }
      searchIndex++;
    }

    // If all sides are enclosed by 1s, then the region is enclosed
    if (leftEnclosed && rightEnclosed && upEnclosed && downEnclosed) {
      enclosedCoordinates.push([rowIndex, cellIndex]);
      arrayData[rowIndex][cellIndex] = '#';
    }
  });
});

console.log(arrayData.map(row => row.join(' ')).join('\n'));
console.log(enclosedCoordinates)
```